# Yahoo Finance using PHP and JSON

Tags: php, json, yahoo, finance

There are alot of question about this topic but mine isnt answered. I'm kinda new to the whole JSON idea so this is what i want.

I want to have stocks visible on my website that changes when the stocks change. I this is what i got so far

```
<?php
    $stockList = "GOOG+YHOO+AAPL+S+CVGW+ANGO+LNDC+WSCI+ZEP+RELL+WOR+RT+MOS+SONC+TISI+UNF+AEHR+RECN+RELL";
    $stockFormat = "snab";

    $host = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv";
    $requestUrl = $host."?s=".$stockList."&f=".$stockFormat."&e=.csv"; // Pull data (download CSV as file)
    $filesize=2000;

    $handle = fopen($requestUrl, "r");
    $raw = fread($handle, $filesize);
    fclose($handle);
    echo $raw;
?>
```

my question is how to wrap that $raw into JSON? I have searched the internet for 2 days now ! and still havnt found the answer !

I hope you guys can help me figure this out. I dont want to make use of YQL thou. This is btw my first post, hope its clear :)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what's the reason for formatting from CSV to JSON?

Comment: You might be able to use YQL to get the data "directly" as JSON.

Comment: Tried YQL it works fine and all but my challenge is to convert the csv to a JSON format and send it out. in code not some website who converts it :) the reason is ... well the challenge :)